# Oracle self Join

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have table in which has three column ID, Start date ,end date. I need to fetch only records for "ID" for which there no records greater than end date for same ID .  Sample  data

```
ID START_DATE END_DATE
----------------------

 1    01-APR-2013              31-MAR-2014 
 1    01-APR-2014              31-MAR-2015 
 2    01-APR-2013              31-MAR-2014 
 3    01-JUN-2013              31-MAY-2014
```

Query should result only

> 2    01-APR-2013               31-MAR-2014
>   3    01-JUN-2013               31-MAY-2014

I tried this.

```
 With Query_Table As (
         Select '1' ID ,To_date('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_date('31-MAR-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual 
         Union
         Select '1' ID ,To_date('01-APR-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_date('31-MAR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual 
         Union
         Select '2' ID,To_date('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_date('31-MAR-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual 
         Union
         Select '3' Id,To_Date('01-JUN-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') From_Date,To_Date('31-JUL-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') End_Date From Dual )
         ,Query_Table2 as (
         Select '1' ID ,To_date('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_date('31-MAR-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual 
         Union
         Select '1' ID ,To_date('01-APR-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_date('31-MAR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual 
         Union
         Select '2' ID,To_date('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_date('31-MAR-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual 
         Union
         Select '3' Id,To_Date('01-JUN-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') from_date,To_Date('31-JUL-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') end_date From Dual )
         Select Id,From_Date,End_Date
         From Query_Table2
         where Query_Table2.id not in (select id from Query_Table where Query_Table2.from_date>Query_Table.end_Date )
```

Comment: And what happens when you try that? Would finding the row with the latest end date for each ID work? And why don't you have any row in your expected results for ID 1?

Comment: My excpected result  should not show any row for ID 1.  as it has already a row whose "from_date" is greater than previous "end_date". My above query gives row for ID 1

Comment: The second row in your sample data does not have any other row for the same ID with a `from_date` greater than its `end_date`. There are no rows for any ID with `from_date` > 31-MAR-2015 for any ID. So I'm afraid I don't understand the logic you need to apply here.

Comment: ..... I need to fetch only records for "ID" for which there no records greater than end date for same ID . Sample data........  based on your requirement seems that `1    01-APR-2014              31-MAR-2015` should also be in the output; or do i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Am I over simplifying this? Or is this as simple as the following?

```
SELECT mst.id, mst.start_date, mst.end_date
  FROM table_x mst
 WHERE (mst.start_date, mst.id) = (SELECT MAX (sub.start_date), MAX (sub.id)
                             FROM table_x sub
                            WHERE sub.start_date = mst.start_date)
```